# why this method has this error?<Returns only some of the code paths.>

Tags: c#

I just studied C#.
I have no idea about this error
'return' not supposed to be inside for loop || if Conditional sentence?

```
class Palindrome
{
    public int ***Solution***(int x, int y)//<<---error happen here :(
    {
        int a = 0;
        int data;
        string DataString;
        int answer;
        for(int i = x; i < 1000; i--)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < 1000; j--)
            {
                data = i * j;
                DataString = data.ToString();
                if (DataString[a] == DataString[DataString.Length - 1 - a])
                {
                    answer = int.Parse(DataString); 
                    return answer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
CS0161: not all code paths return a value
```

Comment: Consider what happens when `Solution( x: 1001, y: 0 )` is called.

Comment: Even if you know that any input will reach a return statement (which isn't true in this case), you still need all of the theoretical code paths to return something. The easiest way to achieve this is to have a return statement at the very end of your function.

Comment: thank u for everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming because you are only returning whenever if condition is matched.
But what happens when if condition is not met. Or Code never reaches to If condition even????
It will never return anything
So you probably need to return something outside your first for loop.

```
class Palindrome
{
    public int ***Solution***(int x, int y)//<<---error happen here :(
    {
        int a = 0;
        int data;
        string DataString;
        int answer;
        for(int i = x; i < 1000; i--)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < 1000; j--)
            {
                data = i * j;
                DataString = data.ToString();
                if (DataString[a] == DataString[DataString.Length - 1 - a])
                {
                    answer = int.Parse(DataString); 
                    return answer;
                }
                
            }
        }
        return 0; //return something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Scenario 1 wouldn't compile, either, because it won't even get to the `if...else` if it doesn't enter both `for` loops.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Thanks for the suggestion. Corrected it now

Answer (score -1):

You have to use return for all code blocks. Up there you are only returning the If code block. make changes according to it and try.

Comment: You don't have to `return` (or `throw`) in all code blocks, just all code _paths_.  Otherwise, there is already an answer, with code, saying this same thing.